# PHP @mention using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am using a regular expression to convert @user name to links.
For example if user enters @Alex Ferguson it should convert Alex Ferguson to hyperlink.
Here it's converting the first name to hyper link and excluding the last name.It looks for the word closer to @, if there is no space between first name and last name it works fine.
Is there any way to convert both first name and last name to hyper link.

Here is my code:

```
 function convert($msg){
 $message = preg_replace(array('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/i'), array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', '$1<a href="">@$2</a>', '$1<a href="index.php?hashtag=$2">#$2</a>'), $msg);
 return $message;
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Is there always a last name? If not, how should the regex decide which parts belong to a username?

Comment: first name and last name is mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general method for this would be:

```
$regex = '~(?i)@[a-z]+[ ][a-z]+~';
$replaced = preg_replace($regex,'<a href="">$0</a>',$string);
```

**Notes**

- I'll leave it for you to fill in the blanks
- One issue with names is the range of allowable characters. What about Julie O'Hara? M.C. Cocoa? etc.

Comment: is it possible to do a callback before converting to links, i want to check whether the user exists in the database or not.

Comment: Absolutely! `preg_replace_callback($regex,function($m) {// do whatever you like here, look up etc, then return your replacement or $0 unnchanged  },$string);`

Comment: should i use preg_replace_callback insted of preg_replace ?

Comment: Well yes, if you're wanting to check the database etc, use the callback function as I showed you in the comment above. If  you need reassurance, you can see the same thing on this [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)  Hope this answers your question.  :)